# Magento2: How to customzie tax in shopping cart page

Tags: magento2, tax

How to customize tax in shopping cart page. If the customer have some certification**(eav_attr)** then not showing tax in all pages.

We already tried `sales_quote_collect_totals_before`

Answer (score 1):

You can observe to the event `sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after` and achieve it.

**File : app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after">
        <observer name="changeTax" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeTax"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**File : app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeTax.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class ChangeTax implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
              $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();
              $product->setTaxClassId(0); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

After searching we got solution for this issue

**vendor/module/etc/event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">              
    <event name="checkout_cart_update_items_after">
        <observer name="updatemessage" instance="DCKAP\Checkout\Observer\UpdateMessage" />
    </event>

</config>
```

**vendor/module/Observer**

```
<?php
namespace DCKAP\Checkout\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class ChangeTaxTotal implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
            $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();
             $product->setTaxClassId(0); // tax class removed.now the price is with no tax

        }
    }
}
```